# why WCF scenario test generation wizard throw that error?what kind or log file i should use?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, scenarios

I'm creating a wcf test and when the WCF Scenario Test Generation Wizard comes up there is an option to create the scenario called :"Capture the message log" then when I give to it a wcf trace file throws an error: messages.svclog is not a valid message log file

[image]

The wcf trace file seems that is not closed :

[image]

when i open the the wcf trace file appears the next window:

[image]

but anyone know how i can close the file? , what i have to do?

Comment: Are you sure the file is closed? Restart your service and then try again. Those files are appended to all the time.

Comment: i just had upload an image where it shows that the wcf trace file seems that is not closed, do you know if that could be the reason?.

Comment: That would be the reason. It's an XML file, and it needs to be closed before it can be read.

Comment: ok, do you think that there is a problem if the binding is nettcp instead of http ?

Comment: or do you know how can i close the file? , sorry for the question but I'm new in this.

Comment: The simplest way is to do an IISRESET. If not, then just restart IIS using the IIS Manager. An interesting cheat is to open the web.config in notepad, type a space, delete it, then save the file. Changing web.config causes a reset of the AppDomain into which the web.config is loaded. Then copy the .svclog file _right away_ before it gets changed again.